# ES6 call with variable inside array that is inside an object with multiple objects or properties

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Took me a lot of time to frame the title, alas it's still hard to comprehend.

Anyway this is what I wanna do, but don't know how to do it, or whether it is even possible, so please enlighten me.

Here it is:

```
const defaults = {
  backgroundcolor: '#000',
  color: '#fff',
  getProps: [
    'some value',
    `${this.backgroundcolor}`,
    `${this.color}`
  ]
};
```

I know I can call it outside of the Object like `defaults.backgroundcolor`, but I wanna know if the above code is achievable too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this` does not have the value you want it to have inside a static declaration.  Javascript doesn't work that way.  You can assign `defaults.getProps` after you've declared the object and then you can refer to other properties in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `getProps` a method, you can make it work:

```js
const defaults = {
 backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 getProps: function () { return [
   'some value',
   `${this.backgroundcolor}`,
   `${this.color}`
 ];}
};

var x = defaults.getProps();

console.log(x);
```

If it has to be a a property that can be accessed without the function parentheses, then use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
const defaults = Object.defineProperty({
        backgroundcolor: '#000',
        color: '#fff',
    }, 'getProps', {
        get: function () { return [
           'some value',
           `${this.backgroundcolor}`,
           `${this.color}`
        ];}
});

var x = defaults.getProps;

console.log(x);
```

You could also make a constructor which you execute immediately:

```js
const defaults = new (function() {
    this.backgroundcolor = '#000';
    this.color = '#fff';
    this.getProps = [
       'some value',
       `${this.backgroundcolor}`,
       `${this.color}`
    ];
})();

var x = defaults.getProps;

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Would I be able to do the same with an anonymous function, using () => ? I tried, didn't get it.

Comment: No, `=>` syntax [does not set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) the `this` keyword.